# Losing Image Quality When Encrypting And Decrypting an Image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jpeg, android-photos

Basically, I scramble all the pixels and then reassemble them. But after the reassembly, I lose a massive amount of image quality and color. I also notice that the file size changes which I thought was odd considering its the same pixels.

[The Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7gdN.jpg)

[The Scrambled Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqEsj.jpg)

[The New Unscrambled Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erjKF.jpg)

Notice a massive loss of color and information. I've tried saving it as a PNG instead of JPEG but that didn't seem to change anything. Here's some code.

```
    pixels = new int[width*height];
    pixelsLength = pixels.length;
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels,0,width,0,0,width,height);
```

This is where I get the pixels array.

```
private void encPhaseOne(){

    load.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgload1);
    int x;
    int y;
    for(int i = 0; i < RAND_ARRAY_SIZE-1; i+=2){
        x = arr1[i];
        y = arr1[i+1];
        rowSwap(x,y);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < RAND_ARRAY_SIZE-1; i+=2){
        x = arr4[i];
        y = arr4[i+1];
        columnSwap(x,y);
    }
}
```

The above is a sample encryption method.

```
private void decPhaseOne(){

    load.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgload3);

    int x;
    int y;

    for(int i = RAND_ARRAY_SIZE-1; i > 0; i-=2){
        x = arr4[i];
        y = arr4[i-1];
        columnSwap(x,y);
    }
    for(int i = RAND_ARRAY_SIZE-1; i > 0; i-=2) {
        x = arr1[i];
        y = arr1[i-1];
        rowSwap(x,y);
    }
}
```

This is its respective decryption.

```
private void complete(){
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels,0,width,0,0,width,height);
    imgUri = getImageUri(this,bitmap);

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(directory, "ENCIMG" + ".JPEG");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.d("path", file.toString());
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        done();
}
```

This is where I save the image.

I can't seem to find where I'm losing so much information